# How to connect Microsoft Dynamic CRM Account using WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm

I want to connect Microsoft Dynamic CRM account using WCF service hosted on server. Currently I can connect to it if I host my service in IIS server but I can't connect when I host my service to our server.

Here is the sample I have created for understanding:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get Data from Crm Call" onclick="checkConnection()" />

function checkConnection() {
    var requestData = {
        //data of CRM like user name password etc
    };

    //Service call
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // url: "http://localhost:13213/Service1.svc/savedata", //this is working fine
            url: "http://mdcportal.biztechconsultancy.com/Service1.svc/savedata/",
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, XMLHttpRequest) {
                debugger;
                //I get success for service call
                alert(data.ResponseData);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("error"+xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message + " Error");
    }
}
```

WCF Service

```
//service call
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public RequestData authentication(CRMCredential objauthentication)
    {
        //get data successfully from objauthentication
        RequestData result = new RequestData();
        try
        {
            List<PostData> itemlist = new List<PostData>();
            ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
            clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = objauthentication.Username;  //Username;
            clientCredentials.UserName.Password = objauthentication.Password;
            Uri oUri = new Uri(objauthentication.Uri);

            //go to catch from following fine
            _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(oUri, null, clientCredentials, null);

            //few code here to populate other information

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.isSuccess = false;
            CallDetails objcalldetail = new CallDetails();
            objcalldetail.code = ex.ToString();
            objcalldetail.message = "CRM authentication failed";
            result.CallDetail = objcalldetail;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Please note that it is working fine if I can try to connect by hosting wcf service in IIS.

Please suggest me if I am missing something.

Comment: You say "Currently I can connect to it if I host my service in IIS server but I can't connect when I host my service to our server", what do you mean by "host my service to our server" are you saying running locally from your machine hosted in iis vs. hosting on a server still in iis?

Comment: @MattDearing Yes. When I run the service in IIS of my system, it is working perfectly. But when I host service to our server (we have server where we host all the services), it throw above error.

Comment: So on your machine it runs in IIS on the server it is hosted as a standalone service?

Comment: @MattDearing I apologies but I am not getting what are you asking. Let me try to explain you. I have hosted service in `hostgator`. But it throw above error. So I have tried to host the service in IIS server of my local system and it works well. Let me know if you still have query.

Comment: Based on the comment my guess is hostgator runs in a lower permission/trust level than what you are running locally. Not sure there is going to be anything you are able to do here.

Comment: @MattDearing Other function in the services works fine, the functions which try to access the Dynamic CRM SDK is not working, Is there any specific permission to use dynamic crm sdk.... In same domain it works fine but if domain change it gives security permission issue. Please suggest. I am really stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120066/discussion-between-nanji-mange-and-matt-dearing).

Comment: Won't be able to join a chat, but I just tried using the sdk and debugging a "partially trusted" console app, per these instructions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164730(v=vs.100).aspx, and got the same error. There must be some assembly in the SDK, or it takes on a dependency, that doesn't allow partial trust callers. With you using a hosting provider that forces your app into partial trust I'm not sure that you'll have options unless the hosting provider offers full trust as well.